# Excel For Each Cell Not Working?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the code to loop through the range. For example, it should be taking the value in cell M53, using it, then running through the code, and doing the same thing with the value in cell M54. The first iteration works, but then it just seems to continuously keep running in cell M53.

I am struggling to work this one out.

```
Sub TestMacro1()

Dim n As Integer
Dim Strike As Range

Set Strike = Range("M53:M54")
n = 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In Strike
    cell.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("E19").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    If Checker = True Then
        Range("E26").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("N53").Offset(n).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The Checker Function is defined as:

```
Function Checker() As Boolean

Dim tmp
Dim c As Object

tmp = False
ActiveSheet.Calculate
ActiveSheet.Calculate

With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set c = .Find("request", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:06"), "TestMacro1"
        tmp = False
    Else
        tmp = True
    End If
End With

Checker = tmp

End Function
```

Comment: what is `Checker`?  I do not see it declared.

Comment: I suspect this is related to the side effect in your `Checker()` function that calls `Application.OnTime`. You should probably exit if it returns false, because it will schedule the macro once *for each additional loop iteration* if you don't. Everything else seems to work fine when I test it.

Comment: @Comintern Sorry I'm not quite getting it, how would the checker function look if I were to incorporate this?

Comment: `If Checker = True Then ... [existing code] ... Else Exit For`

Comment: I've currently got this (sorry it's not pretty), but the problem is...it populates for the first cell fine and pastes the value next it it. It then tries the next cell in the range and enters it, but doesn't paste the value. It then repeats with the first cell again, and so it continues? [link](http://pastebin.com/sdcW9HLN)

Comment: @CuriousStudent what cells are you trying to copy ? copy Cell "E26" , and then which cell should be next ? Cell "E27" or Cell "F26" ?

Comment: @ShaiRado - it should always be E26 over and over. The range (M53 and so on) are different inputs, and I want to grab E26 (the output) each time

Comment: I understand that, but if the first cell in your loop fails the `Checker = True` test, you'll end up calling `Application.OnTime` multiple times unless you paste "request" into `Range("E19")`. Step through it with the debugger.  You'll see that your loop functions just fine, and goes through each cell as expected. But if `.Find("request", LookIn:=xlValues)` returns `Nothing` in `Checker`, you'll re-enter the macro after 6 seconds, and possibly multiple times.

Comment: @Comintern - It is strange though, that even when that condition is satisfied, it doesn't paste the value for the next cell in the range. It does this only for the first one

Comment: Comment out `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and step through it with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
Sub TestMacro2()
    Sub TestMacro2()
Dim cell As Range
Dim Strike As Range
Set Strike = Range("M53:M54")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each cell In Strike
    cell.Copy
    Range("E19").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'fixed range

        If Checker = True Then
            ActiveSheet.Calculate
            Range("E26").Copy
            cell.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
Next cell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow. I've pasted the checker function itself above

Comment: please ignore the "Checker" comment i placed before you edited your post.

Comment: try avoiding using `Select`, you can just use `Range("E26").Copy` and `Range("N53").Offset(n).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: Thanks @ShaiRado, I've made these changes. But is there any reason you can see why the code doesn't loop through the cells properly? It appears to just run on M55, and it continues to run too, continuously populating N54 again and again with the value in M55

Comment: @CuriousStudent what are you trying to achieve? The code is looping through the range and copying cell value and pasting it to Range("E19"). if checker is true you are pasting at fixed Range("N53") + offset by n.

Comment: I want to paste the value in M53, run through the code, paste to N53. Then I want to paste in the value in M54, run through the code, then Paste to N53 + offset 1, etc

Comment: Thanks both. For some reason, it isn't behaving properly and won't loop through the cells. Also - it seems to like to continually populate one cell at the end of the range, repopulating the same number into cell N53 + offset